# Is SSH ControlMaster with Cygwin on Windows actually possible?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, ssh-multiplexing

Has anyone been able to use control master with cygwin on Windows to create multiple sessions without having to log on repeatedly? I need to automate a succession of SSH steps but cannot ask the user to enter the required tokenized password eachtime.

I have configured my cygwin ssh_config with following:

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
```

And I get the following error message on the master when I start a second connection which prompts for the password again:

```
mm_receive_fd: no message header
process_mux_new_session: failed to receive fd 0 from slave
```

I've seen others with this problem but I can't seem to find any solution for this.

Has anyone made this work?

Comment: Off-topic for the question, but using `ControlPath /tmp/...` probably sets you up for an attack where somebody else writes your predictable file name to /tmp first. Use relative path `ControlPath %r@%h:%p` instead, this will put it in your `~/.ssh`.

Comment: For native Win32 OpenSSH [it's in the backlog](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/405). For WSL it just works.

Answer (score 30):

Apparently the conclusion after much searching is that currently it is NOT possible. These were the only links I found that dealt with this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140457/imitating-a-shared-ssh-session-for-scripts-on-windows
    "...but there is no implementation of OpenSSH for Windows which does this (file descriptors over unix sockets do not work in Cygwin)."
and

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SSH_connection_caching
    "Unfortunately if you are using OpenSSH on Cygwin you will not be able to take advantage of connection caching because Cygwin does not currently support file descriptor passing via unix-domain sockets."

Comment: I like this response back in 2008: "Plans, yes, for a long time.  Updates, no." http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-06/msg00280.html

Comment: And here's [confirmation in 2015](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-01/msg00123.html) that no, it's still not possible.  That's too bad.

Answer (score 5):

[Bug 1278 - CYGWIN controlMaster connections don't work.](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278) describes use of ControlMaster/ControlPersist as partially implemented under Cygwin as of December, 2016, but with a qualification that it works only for remote commands and not for connections that require a pseudo terminal.

While this answer was not confirmed under Cygwin, per se, it was validated as true for MSYS2 (based on Cygwin).  openssh under MSYS2 supports ControlMaster/ControlPersist connections for remote commands, but not for interactive sessions.

```
$ cygcheck -V | head -3
cygcheck (msys) 3.0.7
System Checker for Msys
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2019 Cygwin Authors

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

$ pacman -Qi openssh
Name            : openssh
Version         : 8.1p1-1
Description     : Free version of the SSH connectivity tools
Architecture    : i686
URL             : https://www.openssh.com/portable.html
Licenses        : custom:BSD
Groups          : net-utils
Provides        : None
Depends On      : heimdal  libedit  libcrypt  openssl
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : sshpass
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 4.55 MiB
Packager        : Alexey Pavlov <alexpux@gmail.com>
Build Date      : Mon, Oct 14, 2019 1:12:28 AM
Install Date    : Thu, Oct 24, 2019 8:38:48 PM
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

The following errors occur when running `ssh` without a remote command specified:

```
mm_send_fd: sendmsg(2): Broken pipe
mux_client_request_session: send fds failed
```

With remote commands specified, the errors do not occur.

Answer (score 4):

For Cygwin it still seems not possible, but in Windows, it is possible.  I have this working in windows using wsl-ssh-pageant and the Windows Ubuntu Bash/WSL).

Under bash install socat. Then run wsl-ssh-pageant as it says, then with the while loop and export.  If you have your controlmaster under .ssh setup correctly and the directory for ControlPath is created, is should work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to describe, but wsl-ssh-pageant is a tool to access PuTTY's ssh-agent from within WSL. It's got nothing to do with ssh multiplexing, which works out of the box on WSL.

Comment: WSL is virtually Linux... so of course it would work. What doesn't work is any form of openssh multiplexing... cygwin or not - because nobody has implemented it in any way other than through sockets, which Windows doesn't have. The closest light-weight solution is to just use Putty and enable its "reuse connections" feature... I'll post a separate answer about that as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, not Cygwin nor OpenSSH nor Dropbear - but there is one another lightweight ssh multiplexing option on Windows: PuTTY supports "Share SSH connections if possible"

[image]

If you need a console version, I would suggest working your way down this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients#Platform

SSH Multiplexing lowers the initial connection latency substantially because the initial handshake has already taken place. Technically it should be possible - and useful - to implement full UNIX socket functionality on Cygwin - but doing it properly would somewhat of an undertaking. Some of the functionality is there, but it's unlikely to be secure and it's a hack, see [What mechanism is used by MSYS/Cygwin to emulate Unix domain sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086038/what-mechanism-is-used-by-msys-cygwin-to-emulate-unix-domain-sockets)