# What endpoint does the Windows OpenSSH Agent listen on

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-agent

Does anybody know what endpoint the Windows OpenSSH Authentication agent listens on, and how it advertises this so that the Windows `ssh.exe` can communicate with it?

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I recently noticed that my Windows PC has a service called "OpenSSH Authentication Agent", which is disabled by default. When enabled, it works quite well as the ssh-agent for the `ssh.exe` that comes with Windows 10 and later (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`).

In Unix operating systems the `ssh-agent` listens on a Unix socket, and the location of that socket is set in the `SSH_AUTHSOCK` environment variable. However in Windows there is no `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable and the Windows-supplied `ssh.exe` seems to find it anyway.

Furthermore, It's my understanding that Windows does not implement Unix sockets, so `ssh.exe` must be using a different mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It's open source that is hosted on [Github here](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/)

The wrapper tha runs ssh-agent as a Windows service is in the source tree [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/tree/latestw_all/contrib/win32/win32compat/ssh-agent)

And a quick glance of the code ([agent.c](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/latestw_all/contrib/win32/win32compat/ssh-agent/agent.c)) suggests that a Win32 named pipe is the IPC mechanism. You might want to dive deeper into the code including building, running and debugging locally.

Comment: Thanks @selbie. I also think that the `wmain_common.c ` is useful, as it defaults the endpoint to `\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent` if the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is undefined. I'm thinking that's my answer. That makes it a bit difficult for non-Microsoft implementations of `ssh` to use this agent, unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnJeffery - Do the non-Microsoft implementations of `ssh` have a mechanism to communicate with an agent service?  If so, you could probably extend the open source version of win32 ssh-agent to use it.

Comment: I found an excellent blog post by Stuart Leeks, which covers forwarding a Unix socket in WSL to a named pipe in Windows. The link is https://stuartleeks.com/posts/wsl-ssh-key-forward-to-windows/

Comment: Yes that is a potential solution. There is a good SO question where some people have taken the trouble to describe how Cygwin and MSYS2 implementations simulate Unix sockets in Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086038/what-mechanism-is-used-by-msys-cygwin-to-emulate-unix-domain-sockets