# Vagrant windows 7 error in rsync protocol data stream

Tags: ssh, vagrant, rsync, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I have a problem with my Vagrant. When it want to sync the host folder with the VM folder I got this error message:

```
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /c/Users/loow/Documents/internavenue-vagrant/ => /home/vagrant/sync
```

There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
    Please inspect the error message below for more info.

```
Host path: /c/Users/loow/Documents/internavenue-vagrant/
Guest path: /home/vagrant/sync
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=C:/Users/loow/AppData/Local/Temp/ssh.126 -o ControlPersist=10m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/loow/Documents/internavenue-vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key' --exclude .vagrant/ /c/Users/loow/Documents/internavenue-vagrant/ vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/sync
Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

mm_receive_fd: no message header

process_mux_new_session: failed to receive fd 0 from slave

mux_client_request_session: read from master failed: Connection reset by peer

Failed to connect to new control master

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: err
```

I am under Windows 7 and I download the rsync from [there](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync) after change folder name ad take it to the `C:\` and in cmd I added it to the path with the set `PATH=%PATH%;C:\rsync\bin` but I still get this message. I still have installed a Git ssh too, but I dont think it is problem. What can I do for this working, I really have to solve it because I can't sync folders with the VM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is SSH ControlMaster with Cygwin on Windows actually possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959792/is-ssh-controlmaster-with-cygwin-on-windows-actually-possible)